# Параллельные процессы Python Kivy

Tags: python, многопоточность, kivy

Всем привет, есть небольшая программа(парсер интернет магазина), решил придать ей внешний вид, а так же добавил `ProgressBar`. Моя проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы во время парсинга параллельно работал `ProgressBar`. По итогу, я понял, что надо `ProgressBar` запустить в отдельном потоке, но пока затрудняюсь с реализацией этого процесса. Думал, что удастся как-то запустить сразу два процесса, при нажатии одной кнопки, но не вышло.

```
def launch_bar(self, instance):
    self.pb = ProgressBar()
    popup = Popup(title="In process", content=self.pb, size_hint=(0.7,0.3))
    popup.open()
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.go,1)


def go(self, instance):
    self.pb.value += 1
```

Это все относительно `ProgressBar`'а.
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсинг запускается в отдельном потоке, а не прогрессбар. Дело в том что элемент интерфейса не блокирующий, а парсинг блокирует.

На прогрессбар вешается таймер, который смотрит переменную с количеством страниц или что там у Вас. Интерфейс работает в основном потоке.

Обработка запускается по кнопке в новом потоке. Ничего нового изобретать не нужно в большинстве случаев кроме этого указателя таймеру самому на себя:

```
def process(data,progress): ....
    progress[0]+=1
.....
progress = [0] 
t = Thread(target=process,args=(data,progress))
t.start()

events=[]

def tick(t):
    if t.is_alive():
       t.join(timeout=0.5)
       print(progress[0])
    else:
       event.cancel()

ev = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(tick, t, events), 1)
events.append(ev)
t.start()
```

Ещё я люблю `multiprocessing.Pool().map(...)`, но с таким вариантом переменная progress должна быть из multiprocessing.manager. С тредами или переменную привязываешь к контексту (self.progress, global progress) или изменяемый тип передается параметром.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробовать